# Wordpress not showing current site on Mobile...not a caching issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, mobile

I have a wordpress site that was built on top of an older site.

On mobile devices, the old site shows up, even though the URL is the same.

It is not a client side caching issue...Used a phone that has never been to the old site and site serves up the old version, not wordpress.  Clearing cache and incognito do not do anything either.

We pushed the 'clear server cache' button in wordpress...no luck.  It looks like the server is legitimately ignoring wordpress for mobile connections and serving up the old site.

I do not know what else to try.  Hostgator, LAMP server, WP version 6.11.

Is there any way to control Apache like IIS?  (Sorry..I'm a windows guy and know nothing about LAMP.)

FYI here is my .htaccess.  I don't see it doing anything specific in mobile...anything amiss here?

```
#BUILDER-START#
# Enable rewriting.
RewriteEngine on
Header add Vary "User-Agent"
Header add X-Generated "%t"
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 "<h1>Not found<h1>"
## Internal Redirect Loop Protection
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 'iphone|ipad|ipod|android|nokia|ios|opera m(ob|in)i|iemobile|symbian|samsung|sec-|htc|huawei|ericsson|sonyericsson|blackberry|motorola|sagem|kyocera|zte|kddi|docomo|j-phone|kwc|lenovo|lg|mot|softbank|nec|audiovox|alcatel|sharp|sie-|sanyo|sendo|amoi|xda|bird|benq|palm|pantech|panasonic|fly|asus-|baiduispider|googlebot-mobile|nintendo|psp|dalvik|windows ce|foma|brew|webos|fennec|netfront|teleca|obigo|vodafone|up.browser|portalmmm' [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ index_mobile.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ index.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 'iphone|ipad|ipod|android|nokia|ios|opera m(ob|in)i|iemobile|symbian|samsung|sec-|htc|huawei|ericsson|sonyericsson|blackberry|motorola|sagem|kyocera|zte|kddi|docomo|j-phone|kwc|lenovo|lg|mot|softbank|nec|audiovox|alcatel|sharp|sie-|sanyo|sendo|amoi|xda|bird|benq|palm|pantech|panasonic|fly|asus-|baiduispider|googlebot-mobile|nintendo|psp|dalvik|windows ce|foma|brew|webos|fennec|netfront|teleca|obigo|vodafone|up.browser|portalmmm' [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).* $1_mobile.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).* $1.html
#BUILDER-END



# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
    Header set X-nginx-cache "WordPress"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: It appears to be set up to append "_mobile" to the filename when it detects a mobile browser. I'm assuming you haven't created such files and so it's serving the old ones. You can simply remove that section of the .htaccess if you don't want to serve different files to mobile browsers.

Comment: Kevin, that was the issue...ended up chatting with Hostgator and they just re-wrote the htaccess.  FYI pleasantly surprised with Hostgator's support these days.